# Best resources for working on an Rmarkdown/Bookdown project with multiple collaborators?

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I am looking for a resource where it would allow multiple collaborators to work on a single Rmarkdown or Bookdown project. Currently, I am finding that if, for example, I were to make changes on a Rmarkdown document that is in a shared Dropbox, this change will not update to the other collaborators unless they were to logout and restart the documents. Is there perhaps a resource for live-editing? I have thought about Github but it doesn't allow live access. Thanks.

Comment: RStudio Server Pro allows collaborative editing.

Comment: @RalfStubner Would you know if it allows edits to show immediately if two people are editing at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is part of project sharing: https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/r-sessions.html#project-sharing. A quick way to try it is via the quickstart VM: https://www.rstudio.com/products/quickstart/